# Angular 2 http service, how to cover "no response" scenario, not just "error" scenario

Tags: angular, http

I have the code below, which I trigger once every few seconds in order to make sure the server is still alive:

```
private keepAlive(): void {
    this.http.jsonp(serverPingUrl, 'callback').subscribe((res) => {
        // successful ping.
    }, (err) => {
        // the call is ok but returned an error
    });
}
```

What I'd like to do is somehow get notified when the server is not available (no response at all), and in that case, I want to call a function.

Originally, I thought I could put that in the (err) part of the subscription above, but apparently that only gets called if there's an error RESPONSE, and I need to check for NO response... like the request timed out.  Everywhere I've looked has examples for the error block, but nothing about a "no response" scenario.

Comment: Is the `next` handler called when there's no response?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with using next.  After looking it up, it seems like it's mostly useful for when you receive data in interceptors and if you're getting multiple responses from socket connections, not jsonp calls like mine.  Can you tell me a bit about what you have in mind here so I can test it?